# Why are my chilli plant's leaves turning upside down?

Tags: leaves, chili, container-gardening

I have a small chilli plant. It's in a pot and yesterday I put it outside in the sun. When I brought it back inside some of its leaves had turned upside down. What is the problem?

Comment: Please add a photo so we can see what's happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The most likely explanation is too much sun too quickly - the chlorophyll content in the leaves is greatest on the upper surface, and its the chlorophyll that absorbs sunlight. Your plant, being exposed to sun suddenly, flipped its leaves to absorb less of it - this is not an unusual event on pepper plants and it shouldn't affect its fruiting. Next time you want to put it outside, introduce it to sun gradually by standing in a dappled shade spot for a day or three, gradually moving it into full sun as it grows.

Answer (score 1):

I thought they turned the leaves of a night time if it got cold

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17152)

Comment: @blackthumb Please explain why you think this doesn't answer the question of why the leaves turned upside down.

Comment: it's more of an opinion sine they say they think something